# When do we need to use @Injectable on our services in Angular2?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

All:

Im pretty new to Angular2, when I reach dependency injection section, that `@Injectable()` notation make me a lil confused. Just want to make sure my understanding about @Injectable() is correct:

1. `@Injectable()` indicates the class follows it can be injected as service.
2. `@Injectable()` indicates the class follows it has other `@Injectable()` defined service injected into.

Is this pretty much what `@Injectable()` means? Anything else needs to pay special attention about this notation?

And We can not decide which case happens(or both happen) until we look into the class definition, is it correct?

Thanks

Comment: Strictly the first point is true.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Injectable-decorator.html

Comment: @silentsod Thanks, and correction for the second?

Answer (score 17):

I don't know who wrote the [documentation for @Injectable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Injectable-decorator.html) or when it was written, but it is completely misleading:

> A marker metadata that marks a class as available to `Injector` for creation.
>   ...
>   `Injector` will throw `NoAnnotationError` when trying to instantiate a class that does not have `@Injectable` marker.

You can see that this is not true in this [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/nrnN7rT58ay5bvwVXGuc?p=preview). So for your question, (1) is false.

What the `@Injectable` annotation actually does is provide metadata to Angular about what it needs to inject to the service. If the service doesn't need anything injected, then the service doesn't need the metadata. But if it does require injection, and doesn't have the metadata, you will get an error, as Angular can't resolve the parameters to inject.

In the [documentation for dependency injection](http://plnkr.co/edit/nrnN7rT58ay5bvwVXGuc?p=preview), they got it *half* right (with contradicting statements).

> **Why @Injectable()?**
>
> `@Injectable()` marks a class as available to an injector for instantiation. Generally speaking, an injector will report an error when trying to instantiate a class that is not marked as `@Injectable()`.
>
> As it happens, we could have omitted `@Injectable()` from our first version of `HeroService` because it had no injected parameters. But we must have it now that our service has an injected dependency. We need it because Angular requires constructor parameter metadata in order to inject a Logger.

If that doesn't sound contradictory to you, I don't know what does. The first paragraph sounds like the previous `@Injectable` documentation, while the second paragraph got it right.

Just keep in mind that it is just *recommended* that we *always* add the `@Injectable` decorator on all our services as we may later decide that we need to add dependency parameters, but forget the add the `@Injectable` when we do so.

> We recommend adding `@Injectable()` to every service class, even those that don't have dependencies and, therefore, do not technically require it. Here's why:
>
> - **Future proofing:** No need to remember `@Injectable()` when we add a dependency later.
> - **Consistency:** All services follow the same rules, and we don't have to wonder why a decorator is missing.

So your number (2) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very interesting article about this topic: [article link](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2016/12/08/angular-injectable/)

From what I understand if your service does not have the @Injectable decorator but the service has some dependency injection itself - it will give an error.
That is why you have to add the @Injectable() decorator on a service if this service has some dependencies itself. So we add it to every service.