# Can't resolve all parameters for an ngrx/store Action

Tags: angular, typescript2.0, ngrx

I am attempting to create an @ngrx/store action with the following

```
import { ActionReducer, Action } from '@ngrx/store'
import { StoreService } from 'ng2-storeservice'
import { IPatient, Patient } from './patient.service'

export class PatientActions {
  static ADD = '[Patient] ADD';
  static REMOVE = '[Patient] REMOVE';
  static RESET = '[Patient] RESET';

  constructor( public store: StoreService ) { }

  add( path: string, payload: IPatient ) {
    this.store.dispatch( PatientActions.ADD, payload );
  }

  remove( path: string, payload: IPatient ) {
    this.store.dispatch( PatientActions.REMOVE, payload )
  }

  reset( path: string, payload: IPatient ) {
    this.store.dispatch( PatientActions.RESET, payload )
  }
}

export const patient: ActionReducer<IPatient> = (
    state: IPatient = new Patient(), action: Action ) => {
  switch ( action.type ) {
    case PatientActions.ADD:
      return Object.assign( state, action.payload );

    case PatientActions.REMOVE:
      return Object.assign( {}, state, action.payload );

    case PatientActions.RESET:
      return Object.assign( {}, state, action.payload );

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Services are appropriately placed in module that is recognised.
Running the application gives the following error

```
metadata_resolver.js:499Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for PatientActions: (?).
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:31019:19)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:30920:26)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:31063:41
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:31043:19)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:30741:71
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:30732:44)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:30745:50
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

Any help is appreciated.
​

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add the `@Injectable` decorator on the `PatientsAction` class. This is how Angular adds metadata to the class. Without the metadata, Angular will not know how/what to inject.

**See Also:**

- [When do we need to use @Injectable on our services in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41193649/2587435)

Comment: Thanks. Cannot believe I never saw that when I have written so many services! Learn something all the same. Maybe a better error message would help. Such cryptic message is rather useless for identification of the a problem.